# Gridview not detecting checkboxes being checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

What i'm trying to do is execute some code when a checkbox in a gridview is checked, with the code being executed row by row.  I debugged the code and every time returns false despite the checkboxes being checked.  The code i'm trying to execute works if the conditional statement is removed.

```
protected void ShoppingCartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "HIH0HI";

    OleDbConnection myconn = new OleDbConnection();
        myconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|ProjectDatabase.accdb";

    string UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string unpredictable = "";
        bool hi = true;
        unpredictable = row.Cells[1].Text;
        CheckBox chk = row.Cells[0].Controls[1] as CheckBox;
        hi = chk.Checked;
        sb3.Append(hi.ToString());
        if (hi==true)
        {
            string command1 = "insert into Cart ([Username],[GameID]) values (@Username, @GameID)";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command1, myconn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", UserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID", unpredictable);
            myconn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myconn.Close();
        }
    }
    Label1.Text =  sb3.ToString();
}
```

Markup for the button and the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" EmptyDataText ="Data Entry Error">
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Add to Cart?">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbx" runat="server" />
             </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button runat="server" id="ShoppingCartButton" Text="Add to     shopping cart" OnClick="ShoppingCartButton_Click" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to have all this logic happen on the server side? Doesn't it make more sense to have checkbox logic run on the client side instead of requiring a full postback?

Comment: You could try binding to the OnCheckedChanged event and putting a flag property at the class level. Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple one.  Have to enclose any data binding logic in 
    if (!IsPostBack)